# read grid ascii from opendap output using R

Tags: r, ascii, r-grid

I have grid ascii file from opendap output with 4 dimension attributes (time, depth, latitude, longitude), respectively. How to read/import this file into separated XYZ dataframe based on its dimension (i.e. time and depth).

data : https://1drv.ms/t/s!Agp9DFdh1v1vhcpwnWgylJE_aV3E8A?e=FSx2Ex

data structures:

```
# the first column value represent [time][depth][latitude] dimension, respectively

thetao.thetao[2][8][25][13] ## dimension value of [time][depth][latitude][longitude]
[0][0][0], 7058, 7195, 7173, 7083, 6974, 6896, 6879, 6911, 7034, 7222, 7419, 7580, 7717
[0][0][1], 6726, 6857, 6884, 6810, 6725, 6651, 6607, 6613, 6745, 6998, 7262, 7469, 7630
[0][0][2], 6426, 6512, 6564, 6544, 6492, 6443, 6385, 6346, 6422, 6631, 6904, 7129, 7331
[0][0][3], 6361, 6349, 6376, 6414, 6424, 6423, 6399, 6305, 6253, 6283, 6445, 6638, 6862
....
```

XZY output for each time at certain depth

```
# sample for the first row data
latitude    longitude   sst
1   1   7058
1   2   7195
1   3   7173
1   4   7083
1   5   6974
1   6   6896
1   7   6879
1   8   6911
1   9   7034
1   10  7222
1   11  7419
1   12  7580
1   13  7717
....
```

Comment: Which output do you want to see? Add an example to your question...

Comment: actually i need XZY format (lon, lat, sst) for each time and depth dimension

Comment: I still don't understand how to interpret this file. We need an example. Add a table with 3-5 first values.

Comment: i have give more clear information my question

Comment: I have googled a little, so we shouldn't reinvent the wheel :-) Look this article (```package ncdf4```: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/319463953_Using_R_to_read_NetCDF_Files I hope, that it helps